# Android - Error inflating class

Tags: android, layout-inflater, setcontentview

I copy-pasted a basic android snake game code in android studio from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Game/Snakeasimplegamethateveryonecanenjoy.htm)

But i get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo..........Snake}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.example.android.snake.SnakeView
```

and the line of error shows that             `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` has the error.

I checked various similar questions in stackoverflow, but being an absolute beginner i couldnt figure out what the actual problem is.

**EDIT**:

heres the **snake.java**:

```
package com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakefinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Snake extends Activity {

    private SnakeView mSnakeView;

    private static String ICICLE_KEY = "snake-view";

    /**
     * Called when Activity is first created. Turns off the title bar, sets up
     * the content views, and fires up the SnakeView.
     *
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // No Title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSnakeView = (SnakeView) findViewById(R.id.snake);
        mSnakeView.setTextView((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text));

        // Register the listener
        mSnakeView.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener) mSnakeView);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // We were just launched -- set up a new game
            mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.READY);
        } else {
            // We are being restored
            Bundle map = savedInstanceState.getBundle(ICICLE_KEY);
            if (map != null) {
                mSnakeView.restoreState(map);
            } else {
                mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.PAUSE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Pause the game along with the activity
        mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.PAUSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Store the game state
        outState.putBundle(ICICLE_KEY, mSnakeView.saveState());
    }

}
```

**snakeview.java** file :

```
package com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakefinal;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
     * Current mode of application: READY to run, RUNNING, or you have already
     * lost. static final ints are used instead of an enum for performance
     * reasons.
     */

public class SnakeView extends TileView   {
    private static final String TAG = "SnakeView";


    private int mMode = READY;
    public static final int PAUSE = 0;
    public static final int READY = 1;
    public static final int RUNNING = 2;
    public static final int LOSE = 3;

/**
 * Current direction the snake is headed.
 */
private int mDirection = NORTH;
private int mNextDirection = NORTH;
private static final int NORTH = 1;
private static final int SOUTH = 2;
private static final int EAST = 3;
private static final int WEST = 4;

/**
 * Labels for the drawables that will be loaded into the TileView class
 */
private static final int RED_STAR = 1;
private static final int YELLOW_STAR = 2;
private static final int GREEN_STAR = 3;

/**
 * mScore: used to track the number of apples captured mMoveDelay: number of
 * milliseconds between snake movements. This will decrease as apples are
 * captured.
 */
private long mScore = 0;
private long mMoveDelay = 600;
/**
 * mLastMove: tracks the absolute time when the snake last moved, and is
 * used to determine if a move should be made based on mMoveDelay.
 */
private long mLastMove;

/**
 * mStatusText: text shows to the user in some run states
 */
private TextView mStatusText;

/**
 * mSnakeTrail: a list of Coordinates that make up the snake's body
 * mAppleList: the secret location of the juicy apples the snake craves.
 */
private ArrayList<Coordinate> mSnakeTrail = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
private ArrayList<Coordinate> mAppleList = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

/**
 * Everyone needs a little randomness in their life
 */
private static final Random RNG = new Random();

/**
 * Create a simple handler that we can use to cause animation to happen. We
 * set ourselves as a target and we can use the sleep() function to cause an
 * update/invalidate to occur at a later date.
 */
private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();

class RefreshHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        SnakeView.this.update();
        SnakeView.this.invalidate();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
};

/**
 * Constructs a SnakeView based on inflation from XML
 *
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */
public SnakeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initSnakeView();
}

public SnakeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initSnakeView();
}

private void initSnakeView() {
    setFocusable(true);

    Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();

    resetTiles(4);
    loadTile(RED_STAR, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.redstar));
    loadTile(YELLOW_STAR, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.yellowstar));
    loadTile(GREEN_STAR, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.bluestar));

}

private void initNewGame() {
    mSnakeTrail.clear();
    mAppleList.clear();

    // For now we're just going to load up a short default eastbound snake
    // that's just turned north

    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(7, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(6, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(5, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(4, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(3, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(2, 7));
    mNextDirection = NORTH;

    // Two apples to start with
    addRandomApple();
    addRandomApple();

    mMoveDelay = 600;
    mScore = 0;
}

/**
 * Given a ArrayList of coordinates, we need to flatten them into an array
 * of ints before we can stuff them into a map for flattening and storage.
 *
 * @param cvec
 *            : a ArrayList of Coordinate objects
 * @return : a simple array containing the x/y values of the coordinates as
 *         [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3...]
 */
private int[] coordArrayListToArray(ArrayList<Coordinate> cvec) {
    int count = cvec.size();
    int[] rawArray = new int[count * 2];
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        Coordinate c = cvec.get(index);
        rawArray[2 * index] = c.x;
        rawArray[2 * index + 1] = c.y;
    }
    return rawArray;
}

/**
 * Save game state so that the user does not lose anything if the game
 * process is killed while we are in the background.
 *
 * @return a Bundle with this view's state
 */
public Bundle saveState() {
    Bundle map = new Bundle();

    map.putIntArray("mAppleList", coordArrayListToArray(mAppleList));
    map.putInt("mDirection", mDirection);
    map.putInt("mNextDirection", mNextDirection);
    map.putLong("mMoveDelay", mMoveDelay);
    map.putLong("mScore", mScore);
    map.putIntArray("mSnakeTrail", coordArrayListToArray(mSnakeTrail));

    return map;
}

/**
 * Given a flattened array of ordinate pairs, we reconstitute them into a
 * ArrayList of Coordinate objects
 *
 * @param rawArray
 *            : [x1,y1,x2,y2,...]
 * @return a ArrayList of Coordinates
 */
private ArrayList<Coordinate> coordArrayToArrayList(int[] rawArray) {
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coordArrayList = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

    int coordCount = rawArray.length;
    for (int index = 0; index < coordCount; index += 2) {
        Coordinate c = new Coordinate(rawArray[index], rawArray[index + 1]);
        coordArrayList.add(c);
    }
    return coordArrayList;
}

/**
 * Restore game state if our process is being relaunched
 *
 * @param icicle
 *            a Bundle containing the game state
 */
public void restoreState(Bundle icicle) {
    setMode(PAUSE);

    mAppleList = coordArrayToArrayList(icicle.getIntArray("mAppleList"));
    mDirection = icicle.getInt("mDirection");
    mNextDirection = icicle.getInt("mNextDirection");
    mMoveDelay = icicle.getLong("mMoveDelay");
    mScore = icicle.getLong("mScore");
    mSnakeTrail = coordArrayToArrayList(icicle.getIntArray("mSnakeTrail"));
}

/*
 * handles key events in the game. Update the direction our snake is
 * traveling based on the DPAD. Ignore events that would cause the snake to
 * immediately turn back on itself.
 *
 * (non-Javadoc)
 *
 * @see android.view.View#onKeyDown(int, android.os.KeyEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
        if (mMode == READY | mMode == LOSE) {
    /*
     * At the beginning of the game, or the end of a previous one,
     * we should start a new game.
     */
            initNewGame();
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

        if (mMode == PAUSE) {
    /*
     * If the game is merely paused, we should just continue where
     * we left off.
     */
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

        if (mDirection != SOUTH) {
            mNextDirection = NORTH;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        if (mDirection != NORTH) {
            mNextDirection = SOUTH;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
        if (mDirection != EAST) {
            mNextDirection = WEST;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
        if (mDirection != WEST) {
            mNextDirection = EAST;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, msg);
}


public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    float height = this.getHeight();
    float width = this.getWidth();
    float slope = height/width;

    // Only process DOWN action, so it responds as soon as the
    // screen is touched.
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        // Touch event UP
        if ((y < slope*x) && (y < -slope*x + height)) {
            if (mMode == READY | mMode == LOSE) {
                // At the beginning of the game, or the end of a previous one,
                // we should start a new game.
                initNewGame();
                setMode(RUNNING);
                update();
                return (true);
            }

            if (mMode == PAUSE) {
                // If the game is merely paused, we should just continue where
                // we left off.
                setMode(RUNNING);
                update();
                return (true);
            }

            if (mDirection != SOUTH) {
                mNextDirection = NORTH;
            }
            return (true);
        }

        // Touch event DOWN
        if ((y > slope*x) && (y > -slope*x + height)) {
            if (mDirection != NORTH) {
                mNextDirection = SOUTH;
            }
            return (true);
        }

        // Touch event LEFT
        if ((y > slope*x) && (y < (-slope*x + height))) {
            if (mDirection != EAST) {
                mNextDirection = WEST;
            }
            return (true);
        }

        // Touch event RIGHT
        if ((y < slope*x) && (y > -slope*x + height)) {
            if (mDirection != WEST) {
                mNextDirection = EAST;
            }
            return (true);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
/**
 * Sets the TextView that will be used to give information (such as "Game
 * Over" to the user.
 *
 * @param newView
 */
public void setTextView(TextView newView) {
    mStatusText = newView;
}

/**
 * Updates the current mode of the application (RUNNING or PAUSED or the
 * like) as well as sets the visibility of textview for notification
 *
 * @param newMode
 */
public void setMode(int newMode) {
    int oldMode = mMode;
    mMode = newMode;

    if (newMode == RUNNING & oldMode != RUNNING) {
        mStatusText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        update();
        return;
    }

    Resources res = getContext().getResources();
    CharSequence str = "";
    if (newMode == PAUSE) {
        str = res.getText(R.string.mode_pause);
    }
    if (newMode == READY) {
        str = res.getText(R.string.mode_ready);
    }
    if (newMode == LOSE) {
        str = res.getString(R.string.mode_lose_prefix) + mScore
                + res.getString(R.string.mode_lose_suffix);
    }

    mStatusText.setText(str);
    mStatusText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * Selects a random location within the garden that is not currently covered
 * by the snake. Currently _could_ go into an infinite loop if the snake
 * currently fills the garden, but we'll leave discovery of this prize to a
 * truly excellent snake-player.
 *
 */
private void addRandomApple() {
    Coordinate newCoord = null;
    boolean found = false;
    while (!found) {
        // Choose a new location for our apple
        int newX = 1 + RNG.nextInt(mXTileCount - 2);
        int newY = 1 + RNG.nextInt(mYTileCount - 2);
        newCoord = new Coordinate(newX, newY);

        // Make sure it's not already under the snake
        boolean collision = false;
        int snakelength = mSnakeTrail.size();
        for (int index = 0; index < snakelength; index++) {
            if (mSnakeTrail.get(index).equals(newCoord)) {
                collision = true;
            }
        }
        // if we're here and there's been no collision, then we have
        // a good location for an apple. Otherwise, we'll circle back
        // and try again
        found = !collision;
    }
    if (newCoord == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Somehow ended up with a null newCoord!");
    }
    mAppleList.add(newCoord);
}

/**
 * Handles the basic update loop, checking to see if we are in the running
 * state, determining if a move should be made, updating the snake's
 * location.
 */
public void update() {
    if (mMode == RUNNING) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (now - mLastMove > mMoveDelay) {
            clearTiles();
            updateWalls();
            updateSnake();
            updateApples();
            mLastMove = now;
        }
        mRedrawHandler.sleep(mMoveDelay);
    }

}

/**
 * Draws some walls.
 *
 */
private void updateWalls() {
    for (int x = 0; x < mXTileCount; x++) {
        setTile(GREEN_STAR, x, 0);
        setTile(GREEN_STAR, x, mYTileCount - 1);
    }
    for (int y = 1; y < mYTileCount - 1; y++) {
        setTile(GREEN_STAR, 0, y);
        setTile(GREEN_STAR, mXTileCount - 1, y);
    }
}

/**
 * Draws some apples.
 *
 */
private void updateApples() {
    for (Coordinate c : mAppleList) {
        setTile(YELLOW_STAR, c.x, c.y);
    }
}

/**
 * Figure out which way the snake is going, see if he's run into anything
 * (the walls, himself, or an apple). If he's not going to die, we then add
 * to the front and subtract from the rear in order to simulate motion. If
 * we want to grow him, we don't subtract from the rear.
 *
 */
private void updateSnake() {
    boolean growSnake = false;

    // grab the snake by the head
    Coordinate head = mSnakeTrail.get(0);
    Coordinate newHead = new Coordinate(1, 1);

    mDirection = mNextDirection;

    switch (mDirection) {
        case EAST: {
            newHead = new Coordinate(head.x + 1, head.y);
            break;
        }
        case WEST: {
            newHead = new Coordinate(head.x - 1, head.y);
            break;
        }
        case NORTH: {
            newHead = new Coordinate(head.x, head.y - 1);
            break;
        }
        case SOUTH: {
            newHead = new Coordinate(head.x, head.y + 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Collision detection
    // For now we have a 1-square wall around the entire arena
    if ((newHead.x < 1) || (newHead.y < 1) || (newHead.x > mXTileCount - 2)
            || (newHead.y > mYTileCount - 2)) {
        setMode(LOSE);
        return;

    }

    // Look for collisions with itself
    int snakelength = mSnakeTrail.size();
    for (int snakeindex = 0; snakeindex < snakelength; snakeindex++) {
        Coordinate c = mSnakeTrail.get(snakeindex);
        if (c.equals(newHead)) {
            setMode(LOSE);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Look for apples
    int applecount = mAppleList.size();
    for (int appleindex = 0; appleindex < applecount; appleindex++) {
        Coordinate c = mAppleList.get(appleindex);
        if (c.equals(newHead)) {
            mAppleList.remove(c);
            addRandomApple();

            mScore++;
            mMoveDelay *= 0.9;

            growSnake = true;
        }
    }

    // push a new head onto the ArrayList and pull off the tail
    mSnakeTrail.add(0, newHead);
    // except if we want the snake to grow
    if (!growSnake) {
        mSnakeTrail.remove(mSnakeTrail.size() - 1);
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (Coordinate c : mSnakeTrail) {
        if (index == 0) {
            setTile(YELLOW_STAR, c.x, c.y);
        } else {
            setTile(RED_STAR, c.x, c.y);
        }
        index++;
    }

}

/**
 * Simple class containing two integer values and a comparison function.
 * There's probably something I should use instead, but this was quick and
 * easy to build.
 *
 */
private class Coordinate {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Coordinate(int newX, int newY) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }

    public boolean equals(Coordinate other) {
        if (x == other.x && y == other.y) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coordinate: [" + x + "," + y + "]";
    }
}
```

}

**tileview.java**  :

```
package com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakenewww;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * TileView: a View-variant designed for handling arrays of "icons" or other
 * drawables.
 *
 */
class TileView extends View {
/**
 * Parameters controlling the size of the tiles and their range within view.
 * Width/Height are in pixels, and Drawables will be scaled to fit to these
 * dimensions. X/Y Tile Counts are the number of tiles that will be drawn.
 */

protected static int mTileSize;

protected static int mXTileCount;
protected static int mYTileCount;

private static int mXOffset;
private static int mYOffset;

/**
 * A hash that maps integer handles specified by the subclasser to the
 * drawable that will be used for that reference
 */
private Bitmap[] mTileArray;

/**
 * A two-dimensional array of integers in which the number represents the
 * index of the tile that should be drawn at that locations
 */
private int[][] mTileGrid;

private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

public TileView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.TileView);

    mTileSize = a.getInt(R.styleable.TileView_tileSize, 12);

    a.recycle();
}

public TileView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.TileView);

    mTileSize = a.getInt(R.styleable.TileView_tileSize, 12);

    a.recycle();
}

/**
 * Rests the internal array of Bitmaps used for drawing tiles, and sets the
 * maximum index of tiles to be inserted
 *
 * @param tilecount
 */

public void resetTiles(int tilecount) {
    mTileArray = new Bitmap[tilecount];
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mXTileCount = (int) Math.floor(w / mTileSize);
    mYTileCount = (int) Math.floor(h / mTileSize);

    mXOffset = ((w - (mTileSize * mXTileCount)) / 2);
    mYOffset = ((h - (mTileSize * mYTileCount)) / 2);

    mTileGrid = new int[mXTileCount][mYTileCount];
    clearTiles();
}

/**
 * Function to set the specified Drawable as the tile for a particular
 * integer key.
 *
 * @param key
 * @param tile
 */
public void loadTile(int key, Drawable tile) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mTileSize, mTileSize,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    tile.setBounds(0, 0, mTileSize, mTileSize);
    tile.draw(canvas);

    mTileArray[key] = bitmap;
}

/**
 * Resets all tiles to 0 (empty)
 *
 */
public void clearTiles() {
    for (int x = 0; x < mXTileCount; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mYTileCount; y++) {
            setTile(0, x, y);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Used to indicate that a particular tile (set with loadTile and referenced
 * by an integer) should be drawn at the given x/y coordinates during the
 * next invalidate/draw cycle.
 *
 * @param tileindex
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
public void setTile(int tileindex, int x, int y) {
    mTileGrid[x][y] = tileindex;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for (int x = 0; x < mXTileCount; x += 1) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mYTileCount; y += 1) {
            if (mTileGrid[x][y] > 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mTileArray[mTileGrid[x][y]], mXOffset + x
                        * mTileSize, mYOffset + y * mTileSize, mPaint);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

and the **logcat** :

```
> 11-13 00:38:43.336  29231-29231/com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakefinal
> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakefinal, PID: 29231
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakefinal/com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakefinal.Snake}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error
> inflating class com.example.android.snake.SnakeView
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
>             at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.example.android.snake.SnakeView
>             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
>             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>             at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native
> Method)
>             at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
>             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
>             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
>             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
>             at com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakefinal.Snake.onCreate(Snake.java:55)
>             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at
```

Comment: please give more details, post the logcat too.

Comment: Link the onCreate method's contents from your Activity that is causing this (Snake?)

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Probably `SnakeView` is not in the `com.example.android.snake` package. After viewing what you copied looks like it should be `app.test.SnakeView`

Comment: Your snakeview java file you posted is obviously incomplete - we need to see the whole thing, especially including the package and import statements at the top. And we need to see the Activity from which you are attempting to instantiate SnakeView.

Comment: @chrisdowney modified the post ! any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

The error says "Error inflating class com.example.android.snake.SnakeView" but your SnakeView class is "com.example.bharatchamakuri.snakefinal.SnakeView". Those are different, which is why it can't load the class.

Did you forget to change the name of the SnakeView class in your layout file perhaps?